# Android firebase real-time database only shows last submit

Tags: java, android, firebase

I've been following a tutorial on how to save data to the Firebase Realtime Database in Android.

With the tutorial i have managed to get this data to save etc however it only shows the last submitted item.

MainActivity code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // creating variables for
    // EditText and buttons.
    private EditText employeeNameEdt, employeePhoneEdt, employeeAddressEdt;
    private Button sendDatabtn;

    // creating a variable for our
    // Firebase Database.
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

    // creating a variable for our Database
    // Reference for Firebase.
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    // creating a variable for
    // our object class
    EmployeeInfo employeeInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // initializing our edittext and button
        employeeNameEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtEmployeeName);
        employeePhoneEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtEmployeePhoneNumber);
        employeeAddressEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtEmployeeAddress);

        // below line is used to get the
        // instance of our FIrebase database.
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        // below line is used to get reference for our database.
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("EmployeeInfo");

        // initializing our object
        // class variable.
        employeeInfo = new EmployeeInfo();

        sendDatabtn = findViewById(R.id.idBtnSendData);

        // adding on click listener for our button.
        sendDatabtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // getting text from our edittext fields.
                String name = employeeNameEdt.getText().toString();
                String phone = employeePhoneEdt.getText().toString();
                String address = employeeAddressEdt.getText().toString();

                // below line is for checking weather the
                // edittext fields are empty or not.
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && TextUtils.isEmpty(phone) && TextUtils.isEmpty(address)) {
                    // if the text fields are empty
                    // then show the below message.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please add some data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // else call the method to add
                    // data to our database.
                    addDatatoFirebase(name, phone, address);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addDatatoFirebase(String name, String phone, String address) {
        // below 3 lines of code is used to set
        // data in our object class.
        employeeInfo.setEmployeeName(name);
        employeeInfo.setEmployeeContactNumber(phone);
        employeeInfo.setEmployeeAddress(address);

        // we are use add value event listener method
        // which is called with database reference.
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // inside the method of on Data change we are setting
                // our object class to our database reference.
                // data base reference will sends data to firebase.
                databaseReference.setValue(employeeInfo);

                // after adding this data we are showing toast message.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "data added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                // if the data is not added or it is cancelled then
                // we are displaying a failure toast message.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to add data " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EmployeeInfo code:

```
public class EmployeeInfo {

    // string variable for
    // storing employee name.
    private String employeeName;

    // string variable for storing
    // employee contact number
    private String employeeContactNumber;

    // string variable for storing
    // employee address.
    private String employeeAddress;

    // an empty constructor is
    // required when using
    // Firebase Realtime Database.
    public EmployeeInfo() {

    }

    // created getter and setter methods
    // for all our variables.
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    public String getEmployeeContactNumber() {
        return employeeContactNumber;
    }

    public void setEmployeeContactNumber(String employeeContactNumber) {
        this.employeeContactNumber = employeeContactNumber;
    }

    public String getEmployeeAddress() {
        return employeeAddress;
    }

    public void setEmployeeAddress(String employeeAddress) {
        this.employeeAddress = employeeAddress;
    }
}
```

Has anyone ever encountered this in Firebase. I have been looking for other tutorials which had ended up exactly like this so I'm not sure whether it is something in the code that is wrong or with my Firebase database.

Comment: Aren't you entering into an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

As firebase overwrites the previous data you have entered.

You can use a `.push()` function like this before your `setValue`.

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EmployeeInfo");
```

Then,

```
database.push().setValue(employeeObject);
```

The `.push()` method creates a child with a unique key in your database.

Try checking firebase docs for more info
[Save Data on Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push)
, [Read and Write on firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?utm_source=studio)

The key is like this [Firebase RTDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJH4G.png)